# Using PHP if and else statements to search multiple values in table

Tags: php

I am trying to get the following to happen:

if "field_ListingID" = h100 then show div x

or if "field_ListingID" = h200 then show same div x

Basically, within the same table1, I have 2 values "h100 "& "h200". I am able to pull just one value fine, but how do I pull if red or if blue.

Here is the code I have currently that is working for just one value. I tried placing the same php code for "h100" under the else statement, but that generated errors:

```
<?php if ($row["field_ListingID"]=="h100"){ ?>
      <div class="featured-property">
      <a href="#">
      <div class="inner-logo"><img src="images/inner-logo.png" alt="LOGO" width="136" height="41" /></div>
      <div class="bg-txt">
      <div class="star-icon"></div>
      <div class="txt"><p>Featured <span>Property</span></p></div>          
      </div>
      </a>
      </div>

      <?php } else { ?>          

      <div style="margin-top: 20px; min-height:55px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <?php }?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `but that generated errors` what errors?

Comment: have you tried echoing the div??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this, I added the or operator (||) to your if statement:

```
<?php if ($row["field_ListingID"]=="h100" || $row["field_ListingID"]=="h200" ){ ?>
  <div class="featured-property">
  <a href="#">
  <div class="inner-logo"><img src="images/inner-logo.png" alt="LOGO" width="136" height="41" /></div>
  <div class="bg-txt">
  <div class="star-icon"></div>
  <div class="txt"><p>Featured <span>Property</span></p></div>          
  </div>
  </a>
  </div>

  <?php } else { ?>          

  <div style="margin-top: 20px; min-height:55px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <?php }?>
```

Comment: That worked! Awesome thanks. Question if I have a space such as "h100 red" do I need to do %20 or something? When I add spaces it doesn't return anything...

Comment: if you have "h100 red" in your database then == "h100 red" should work, although you might need to trim any extra whitespace.

Comment: It is there, but not pulling it... I am able to get h200 so I know it's working, but the moment I add a space, it doesn't want to fetch that field. Thanks for the reply!